# Please can you explain this code for me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

recently I have been getting into using unity for game making. I am a complete novice with this software so am doing a Roll-A-Ball project provided by unity. There is one piece of code though, that I am struggling to understand. This code is supposed to move the ball across the game plane. Please can you explain it to me.

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed;
        void FixedUpdate()
        {

            float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
            float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

            Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

            rigidbody.AddForce (movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        }

    }
```

Comment: not that it has anything to do with it, but the naming/units are so fudged: distance (m) * speed (m/s) * time (s) = m^2 =/= Force

Answer (score 2):

Vector3 creates a vector given x, y, z coordinates. Your 'y' is constant (0.0f) because the ball is moving on a plane.

`moveHorizontal` and `moveVertical` are getting the mouse coordinates and the rigidBody (ball) is moved according to that.

`FixedUpdate` gets called every frame.

Answer (score -2):

Get the X and Y coordinates. Creates the location and moves the ball using that speed by calling AddForce.